# javascript if not empty element add function return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, return, indexof, angularjs-filter

I want filter mysql with angularjs.

[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toplumdusmani/zcgs7yf6/10/)

when you check tv button and click submit. (tv button values ​​= 2) angularjs filter find 2 in the amenities column. this is working. but when the TV and CABLE TV check and click submit filter is not working. Because my filter code is bad.

```html
$scope.am_en = function()
{
$scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
return location.amenities.indexOf(1)==0;
};
}
```

how to change this line indexOf(1)

this get one value indexOf(1) i want multiple value indexOf('1,7,9,11') Indexof may be another method ?

**Html:**

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="1" id="map-search-amenities-1" ng-checked="false">
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="2" id="map-search-amenities-2" ng-checked="false">
..vs
<button id="more_filter_submit" ng-click="am_en();">Submit</button>
```

**I try this but not working:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$scope.am_en = function(){
$scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
var xC = $(".hosting_amenities input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
var xxc = "["+xC+"]";
var k1 = xxc.indexOf(1)!==-1;
var k2 = xxc.indexOf(2)!==-1;
var k3 = xxc.indexOf(3)!==-1;
...

var zz1 = location.amenities.indexOf(1)==0;
var zz2 = location.amenities.indexOf(2)==0;
var zz3 = location.amenities.indexOf(3)==0;
...

return zz1 || zz2 || zz3 || ...;
};
}
```

**Description:**

```html
k1 == zz1

k2 == zz2
```

**I want to:** 
If k1 equals true add this phrase return : || zz1
If the element is present add return OR element

**For Example 1:**

```html
if (k1 == true) ? "k1":""; 

if (k2 == true) ? "|| k2 ":"";  

if (k3 == true) ? "|| k3 ":"";

return k1 || k3;
```

**For Example 2:**

```html
k1 == false; 

k2 == true; 

k3 == true;

k4 == true;

return k2 || k3 || k4;
```

Comment: I'm under the impression here, that a rethink of the whole logic stack would be useful. Any time you see "this, or that if this, or if that but not the other then the thing or the other thing...", you're building a dangerously brittle and difficult to debug house of cards. You generally can get a much better solution by abstracting the problem and usually rethinking in terms of a data structure or reducing the problem in logical steps, generally by processing with instructions (functional this and that).

Comment: I also don't know what "not add result" means.

Comment: I do not want return added

Comment: mysql > room (table)> amenities (column) = "1,3,5,7,9,15,21" i want filtering checkbox. if user click checkbox 1 (value=1) finding amenities table if 1 indexof amenities column show result. (My English is very bad)

Comment: So, if I get what you're doing, you have a list of Rooms, and you want users to be able to see the Amenities for the Room they select. You associate multiple amenities with a room by storing a comma delimited string of numbers in an "Amenities" column. Each of those numbers corresponds to an Amenity item (stored in another table?). So when a user selects a Room, you want to retrieve those Amenity items and display them. 

That correct?

Comment: Yes I want this. True

Comment: this is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/toplumdusmani/zcgs7yf6/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your response to my restatement (yes, true), here you go:

```
let rooms = [ 
 { name : 'Room1', amenities : '1,3' },
 { name : 'Room2', amenities : '2,4' },
 { name : 'Room3', amenities : '1,2,3' },
 { name : 'Room4', amenities : '2,3,4' }
 ];

 let amenities = [ 
    { id : '1', name : 'Amenity1' },
    { id : '2', name : 'Amenity2' },
    { id : '3', name : 'Amenity3' },
    { id : '4', name : 'Amenity4' },
    ];

 function getAmenities ( room ) {

    // Turn the room amenity ids into an array
    let ids_array = room.amenities.split ( ',' );

    // Filter the amenities table to get the array of amenities for this room
    return amenities.filter ( x => {
        return ( ids_array.indexOf ( x.id ) !== -1 );
    } );
 }

 // Show amenities for a given room
 rooms.forEach ( x => { console.log ( getAmenities ( x ) ) } )
```